# php arrays - remove duplication and corresponding value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an 2d array that contains a 'title' and 'url' (both strings) as shown below. Is it possible to check for duplicates in the 'url' and if they exist, delete the corresponding 'title' too?

```
array
      0 => 
        array
          'title' => string 'China - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia'
          'url' => string 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China'
      1 => 
        array
          'title' => string 'China'
          'url' => string 'http://www.state.gov/r/pa/ei/bgn/18902.htm'
      2 => 
        array
          'title' => string 'China | World news | The Guardian'
          'url' => string 'http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/china'
      3 => 
        array
          'title' => string 'China Travel Information and Travel Guide - Lonely Planet'
          'url' => string 'http://www.lonelyplanet.com/china'
      4 => 
        array
          'title' => string 'ChinaToday.com'
          'url' => string 'http://www.chinatoday.com/'
```

Comment: Which title? The first one? The last one? All? What is the problem you've faced?

Comment: The only correct answer to this would be "Yes, it is possible".

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I would suggest to setup a small class that has 'title' and 'url' as its attributes with a simple constructor that populates them, then use a one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function it could do the job

```
function super_unique($array,$key)
{
   $temp_array = array();

   foreach ($array as &$v) {

       if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key]]))

       $temp_array[$v[$key]] =& $v;

   }
   $array = array_values($temp_array);
   return $array;
}

$yourearray = super_unique($arr,'url');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. You guys are fast!

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are happy with using the last value of the url you could

```
foreach($array as $subarray) {
    $output[$subarray['url']] = $subarray['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$originals = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if(!isset($originals[$value['url']])) {
      $originals[$value['url']] = true;
   }
   else {
      // exists already, delete entry
      unset($array[$key]);
   }
}
```